# Custom iOS "load more" button in row list

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm using a UItableview with a scrolling list. Now I have the default "load more" button that loads 10 objects at a time. It destroys the interface. Any ideas on how to customize it? A tried a few things but we no luck. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try implementing this method that Parse provides for customizing the "Load more" cell:

```
// Override to customize the look of the cell that allows the user to load the next page of objects.
// The default implementation is a UITableViewCellStyleDefault cell with simple labels.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NextPage";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Load more...";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you also happen to know how to change the height of NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NextPage";

Comment: @user3615707 That's just the identifier, that's not on the cell anywhere

Comment: Ok. So it's not possible to change the size of that load more cell?

Comment: @user3615707 I believe you can if you use a custom cell, and you can use heightForRowAtIndexPath too...

Comment: Thanks mate. Any examples?

Comment: @user3615707 check this out: https://gist.github.com/jamesyu/ba03c1a550f14f88f95d

Answer (score 0):

Well there is not much you can do with Parse controller in terms of customization. Also the animation of that controller seems to be a bit clunky. I also got a bunch of memory errors while using the component with latest IOs 9.

For that same reason I've replaced the existing Parse controller with the following. Gave me much more control over the animations and design than the standard PARSE controller.

If you want to reverse the order of the tableview to look like a messenger app please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148367/swift-start-tableview-from-bottom-reverse-tableview/34256198#34256198)

**add global variables**

```
 var objects = [PFObject(className: "Posts")]
 var lockScrollSensor = false
 let objectsPerPage = 10
```

**add to viewDidLoad**

```
//blank screen
let blankView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,     self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height - 60))
blankView.tag = 101
blankView.backgroundColor = customColorYellow()
self.view.addSubview(blankView)
self.tableView.backgroundColor = customColorYellow()
// load tableview
tableViewFirstLoad()
```

**Detect the position of tableview scroll to either call refresh or next page**

```
 override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
        let scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
        let scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

        // refresh - touch top
        if (scrollOffset < -60)
        {
            if lockScrollSensor == false {
                // stop method from non stop calling
                lockScrollSensor = true

                // loader
                let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.parentViewController?.view, animated: true)
                spinningActivity.color = UIColor.clearColor()
                spinningActivity.activityIndicatorColor = customColorRed()
                spinningActivity.yOffset = -Float((self.parentViewController?.view.frame.height)!/2) + 95

                // call method to load more
                self.tableViewRefresh({ (done) -> Void in
                    if done == true
                    {
                        // stop loader and free method
                        spinningActivity.hide(true, afterDelay: 0)
                        self.lockScrollSensor = false

                        // animate tableview
                        self.tableView.contentOffset.y = -60
                        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
                            self.tableView.contentOffset.y = 0
                                }, completion: nil)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        // load more -  touch down
        else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight > scrollContentSizeHeight)
        {
            if lockScrollSensor == false {
                // stop method from non stop calling
                lockScrollSensor = true
                // start loader
                let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.parentViewController?.view, animated: true)
                spinningActivity.color = customColorYellow()
                spinningActivity.yOffset = (Float(tableView.frame.size.height)/2)-25
                // call method to load more
                self.tableViewLoadMore({ (done) -> Void in
                    if done == true {
                        self.lockScrollSensor = false
                        spinningActivity.hide(true)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

**Refresh or next page methods that will load your PFObject array.**

```
// first load
func tableViewFirstLoad(result: (done: Bool) -> Void){
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query = segueDataChecker()
    // limit objects
    query.limit = objectsPerPage
    // get objects
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil
        {
            result(done: true)
            let alertView = createDefaultAlertError(message: "\(error!.localizedDescription.capitalizedString)", actions: [UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)])
            self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            // clean array
            self.objects.removeAll()
            // populate array
            for eachPost in posts!
            {
                if self.objects.count < self.objectsPerPage
                {
                    self.objects.append(eachPost as! PFObject)
                }
            }
            // reload and send back it has finished
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            result(done: true)
            self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "pattern_clear_white.pdf")!)
            // remove uiview
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
                if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(101)
                {
                    viewWithTag.alpha = 0
                }
                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

// refresh existing content
func tableViewRefresh(result: (done: Bool) -> Void){
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query = segueDataChecker()
    // limit objects
    query.limit = self.objects.count
    // save number of objects already loaded
    let actualNumberOfPosts = self.objects.count
    // get objects
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil
        {
            result(done: true)
            let alertView = createDefaultAlertError(message: "\(error!.localizedDescription.capitalizedString)", actions: [UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)])
            self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            // clean array
            self.objects.removeAll()
            // populate array with same updated objects
            for eachPost in posts!
            {
                if self.objects.count < actualNumberOfPosts
                {
                    self.objects.append(eachPost as! PFObject)
                }
            }
            // reload and send back it has finished
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            result(done: true)
        }
    }
}

// load next results
func tableViewLoadMore(result: (done: Bool) -> Void){
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query = segueDataChecker()
    // skip objects already loaded
    query.skip = self.objects.count; // skip the first 20 results
    // limit results to next page amount
    query.limit = objectsPerPage
    // save number of objects already loaded
    let actualNumberOfPosts = self.objects.count
    // get objects
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil
        {
            result(done: true)
            let alertView = createDefaultAlertError(message: "\(error!.localizedDescription.capitalizedString)", actions: [UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)])
            self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            // if there anything new
            if posts?.count != 0
            {
                // populate array with new objects
                for eachPost in posts!
                {
                    if (self.objects.count < self.objectsPerPage + actualNumberOfPosts)
                    {
                        self.objects.append(eachPost as! PFObject)
                    }
                }
                // reload and send back it has finished
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                result(done: true)
                // slide tablview one result down
                let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: actualNumberOfPosts, inSection: 0)
                self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(newIndexPath , atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None, animated: true)
            }
                // if there is nothing new
            else
            {
                result(done: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```