# swift start tableView from bottom (reverse tableView)

Tags: swift, ios8, tableview, xcode6

Is it possible to reverse order a tableView? I search a lot for a solution but nothing works.

The effect is like whatsapp chat.

A normal tableView is:

```
----------
label 1
----------
label 2
----------
label 3
----------
empty
----------
empty
----------

scroll direction
   |
   |
   v
```

Desired result:

```
----------
empty
----------
empty
----------
empty
----------
empty
----------
label 3
----------
label 2
----------
label 1
----------

 scroll direction
      ^
      |
      |
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `cell.setTitle.text = myArray.reversed()[indexPath.row]` Reversing your array will do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just scroll to the end and do the same whenever you insert a cell.

```
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(bottomIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom,
          animated: true)
```

Comment: scroll to the end don't reverse the order of cell :(

Comment: I thought you have already done that. Just return the correct cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()`.

Comment: i try again but doesn't work. First i reverse the data of tableview then i set a var with first indexpath and then i call a func with scrollToRowAtIndexPath but the tableview staty on top again. I try again .. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To complement the answer above I've included the methods to load, load more and refresh using Parse. Or you can replace Parse by any other fetch method you like.

**First load**

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Comments")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    // limit the number of objects
    query.limit = objectsPerPage
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (comments: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // clean array if loading for the first time
        self.objects.removeAll()
        for eachComment in comments!
            if self.objects.count < self.objectsPerPage
            {
                self.objects.append(eachComment as! PFObject)
            }
        }

        // reverse the array
        self.objects = self.objects.reverse()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.objects.count - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false)
```

**To load more**

```
    // for the query
    //skip already loaded objects
    query.skip = self.objects.count; 
    // limit the number of objects
    query.limit = objectsPerPage
    // find the number of objects already loaded
    let numberOfAlreadyLoadedObjects = self.objects.count

    // add your  query.findObjects here

    // correct the order to update the array in the right order
    self.objects = self.objects.reverse()

    // add new posts
    for eachComment in comments!
            if (self.objects.count < self.objectsPerPage + numberOfAlreadyLoadedObjects)
            {
                self.objects.append(eachComment as! PFObject)
            }
    }

    // reverse again
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    let lastIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.objectsPerPage - 2 , inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastIndex, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
```

**To refresh**

```
    // skip already loaded objects
    let numberOfAlreadyLoadedObjects = self.objects.count
    query.skip = numberOfAlreadyLoadedObjects

    // add your  query.findObjects here

    // correct the order
    self.objects = self.objects.reverse()

    // count the number of new objects found
    let newObjectsFound = comments?.count
    // append just the new ones
    for eachComment in comments!
    {
            if self.objects.count < numberOfAlreadyLoadedObjects + newObjectsFound!
            {
                self.objects.append(eachComment as! PFObject)
            }
     }
     // reverse
     self.objects = self.objects.reverse()

     self.tableView.reloadData()
     let lastIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.objects.count - 1, inSection: 0)
     self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastIndex, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Al-Hamdulellah Solution is find
Only reverse your array and load it like :

var messagesArray = string

self.messagesArray = self.messageArray.reversed()

chat App

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

and inside cells:

```
transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```